# MongoDB: Get count of different data in sub-documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have documents in my `run` collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d4410544c96d6f6578f893"), 
    "runName" : "1439973637614",
    "suiteList": [
        {
            "suiteStatus": "PASS"
        },
        {
            "suiteStatus": "PASS"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d44eb4c0422e7b8bffe76b"), 
    "runName" : "1439977140396",
    "suiteList": [
        {
            "suiteStatus": "FAIL"
        },
        {
            "suiteStatus": "PASS"
        }
    ]

}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d44f0bc0422e7b8bffe76f"), 
    "runName" : "1439977227370",
    "suiteList": [
        {
            "suiteStatus": "FAIL"
        },
        {
            "suiteStatus": "FAIL"
        }
    ]

}
```

Now I want to get the output as follows:

```
{
    "runName" : "1439973637614",
    {
        "pass": 2,
        "fail": 0
    }
}

{
    "runName" : "1439977140396",
    {
        "pass": 1,
        "fail": 1
    }
}

{
    "runName" : "1439977227370",
    {
        "pass": 0,
        "fail": 2
    }
}
```

I know on how to get the list of pass and fail counts in suiteList at over all level using this:

```
db.testruns.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$suiteList" },
    { $group: { _id: "$suiteList.suiteStatus", count: { $sum: 1 } } }
]);
```

But I'm not sure on how to achieve the expected output that I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your aggregation query need to some modification you should use [$cond](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) in group so aggregation like this :

```
db.testruns.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$suiteList"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$runName",
        "pass": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$eq": ["$suiteList.suiteStatus", "PASS"]
                    },
                    "then": 1,
                    "else": 0
                }
            }
        },
        "fail": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$eq": ["$suiteList.suiteStatus", "FAIL"]
                    },
                    "then": 1,
                    "else": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: You are awesome. It really shows that I've to read Mongo's documentation in deep.